# Send e-mail from a form (only HTML, javascript)

Tags: html, email, forms, send

Send e-mail from a form, here is the the link to basic HTML code:
[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail)

After writing a comment, name and email and clicking Send button the Outlook Express starts-
is it possible to send message immediately (using only HTML, maybe javascript)?

Or maybe is there something that can be done so that the Outlook Express doesnt ask again to submit a name and email?

Regards

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please don't post *comments* or *questions* as **answers**. To post a comment, use the `add comment` link below the answer you'd like to comment on. To post a question, use the `Ask Question` button. To update a question, use the `edit` link below the question you'd like to edit. To post an answer, obviously use the box below the "Your **Answer** ". No, answers are not equal to comments or questions.

Answer (score 4):

no, not in pure Javascript. Sending email requires server-side processing.

There are several website sthat will let you generate simple email forms, check out: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=email+form+generator&aq=5&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=email+form

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea, that relies on the client having an adequate mail client installed on their computer. What that does is uses their email address to send an email to the email address you specified. It completely relies on the client and has absolutely NOTHING to do with your server. There's nothing you can do on your page to speed up the process.